# Hoverfly Identification Wing Resting Position

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've found an interesting insect which I believe to be a hoverfly:

[image: Hoverfly Top]
[image: Hoverfly Side]

*length: approximately 1/2 inch.*

However when compared to the [Wikipedia poster on Syrphidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoverfly#/media/File:Syrphidae_poster.jpg) or the [InsectIdentification.org Hoverfly entry](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Hover-Fly-Eupeodes) (as well as the flower fly entries) the resting state of the wings differ. In my photographs the wings are resting above the back while hoverflies appear to keep their wings extended.

I know wing position is important in identification, i.e. dragonfly vs damselfly, moth vs butterfly. Does it matter with true flies?

Comment: Your geographic location would help in going deeper (if it's any consolation, you _do_ have the family right).  A better size indicator (say, a distance shot) would also help.  If you're in North America, the site bugguide.net should be your next stop; if in Europe, diptera.info is a good place to start (either way, given how many species of hoverflies exist, you will be spoiled for choice).

Comment: You're right, that family is large. Though I'm not interested in tracking down the exact species. I want to know if the wing resting position can be a species indicator, or just a matter of the insect's personal preference and time of day of particular photograph. Most of the [Syrphidae samples from bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/196/bgpage) are shown with open wings, with some exception.

Comment: This is indeed a hoverfly. Most if not all hoverflies fold their wings in this position when not flying.

Comment: @RHA: that's exactly the answer I'm looking for. If you could write a brief summary detailing certain unimportant aspects of insect identification for two or three common families of insects - i.e. wing resting position, antenna resting position - I think it would be a very useful acceptable answer.